# Passing a function as a prop to update state in parent component in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call a method that will update the state in a react app.  The state and method are defined in the parent component, and I've passed the function down to this component that will be doing the UI event.  (selecting from a select tag).  However my function keeps returning undefined from this component.

```
class Book extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onShelfChange: PropTypes.func
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value})
    console.log('book:', this.props.book.title, 'shelf:', event.target.value)
    onShelfChange(this.props.book.id, event.target.value)
  }
  render() {
  const { book } = this.props

  return(
       <div>
          <li key={choice.id}>
        <div>
          <select value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">Want to Read</option>
            <option value="c">c</option>
            <option value="d">d</option>
          </select>
```

Comment: *"However my function keeps returning undefined from this component."* What do you mean by that? Event handlers usually don't *return* anything. What exactly is undefined? Which function are you talking about?

Comment: Please offer more code and information. Where is your parent component's code?  If you mean "onShelfChange" give you a undeifned, please try to change it to this.props.onShelfChange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this.props` before the `onShelfChange` function, as it has sent to this component from the parent.
Can you change the following section:

```
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value})
    console.log('book:', this.props.book.title, 'shelf:', event.target.value)
    this.props.onShelfChange(this.props.book.id, event.target.value)
  }
```

Comment: You should explain what you have changed and why.

Comment: @FelixKling, I added some explanation.